# Trying to deploy an app on heroku , Error: nltk.downloader (runtime warning)

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, nltk, warnings

I'm getting the following error due to which, my deployed app is not viewable, please help me to
resolve this issue:

```sh
Downloading NLTK packages: wordnet punkt stopwords vader_lexicon


/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/runpy.py:127: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
```

Comment: install nltk packages https://www.nltk.org/data.html

Comment: Yeah, I also included nltk in requirements.txt file & also separately created nltk.txt file which includes [wordnet punkt stopwords vader_lexicon]

Comment: Did you solve this?